# How to convert Dictionary<int, long> to string array/list?

Tags: c#, .net, arrays, string, dictionary

I would like to convert a Dictionary to a string array (or list)
The string array needs to be returned like this: "ID, PTS" where int is ID and long is PTS.

Please help!
Thanks, 
~Nikku.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
var strings = dict.Select(item => string.Format("{0}, {1}", item.Key, item.Value));
```

Note that this returns an enumerator. Whether you want the result in the form of `string[]` or `List<string>` you should use `.ToArray()` or `.ToList()`, respectively.

Comment: That's neither an array nor a list. You need either `.ToList()` or `.ToArray()` to realise it as a collection, now it's just an enumerator that can read from the dictionary.

Comment: @Guffa Yep, that is true. I left it out on purpose but I suppose according to the question it should be brought to the OPs attention.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it like this:

```
string[] arr =
  theDictionary
  .Select(kvp => kvp.Key.ToString() + ", " + kvp.Value.ToString())
  .ToArray();
```

Answer (score 1):

The simple answer is to iterate over the dictionary, and copy the values into a string list.

```
Dictionary<int, long> dict = new Dictionary<int, long>();

// If you like Linq. Stick a .ToArray() or .ToList() at the end, or leave it as IEnumerable<string>
var stringList = dict.Select(kvp => kvp.Key.ToString() + ", " + kvp.Value.ToString());

// If you don't like Linq.
List<string> stringList2 = new List<string>();
foreach (KeyValuePair<int, long> kvp in dict)
{
    stringList2.Add(kvp.Key.ToString() + ", " + kvp.Value.ToString());
}
```